# JSF 2.2: request-param in navigation-rule not found

Tags: jsf-2.2, faces-config

I have a faces-config.xml that contains a lot of navigation rules but I'm not able to get a redirect-param in my page.

I've searched a lot about this issue but I couldn't find any helping response.

detail.xhtml:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.delete()}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.deletionSuccess}" value="true" />
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?"
</p:commandLink>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/myDetailPage.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>deletionSuccess</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/myOverviewPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Java-Bean:

```
   private String deletionSuccess;

    public String delete() {
        // do something
        return "deletionSuccess";
    }
    public void setDeletionSuccess(String deletionSuccess) { this.deletionSuccess = deletionSuccess; }

    public String getDeletionSuccess() { return deletionSuccess; }
```

overview.xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="deletionSuccess" value="#{bean.deletionSuccess}"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.init}"/>
</f:metadata>
...
<h:form id="mainform" class="form-horizontal overview" role="form" method="post">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="row" rendered="#{!empty housePlantBean.deletionSuccess}">
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I get the redirect-param in my XHTML-page?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work in such way.

First of all you need to have defined `<f:viewParam>` on `myOverviewPage.xhtml` facelet, eg:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="deletionSuccess" value="#{bean.deletionSuccess}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

I suppose you had it defined.

The easies way to pass params is use `<h:button>` or `<h:link>` on `myDetailPage.xhtml` facelet, eg:

```
<h:button outcome="deletionSuccess">
    <f:param name="deletionSuccess" value="#{true}"/>
</h:button>
```

but there is no invocation of `public String delete()` method.

So if you want to have redirection and invocation of this method you should use `<h:commandButton>` or `<h:commandLink>`, eg:

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.delete}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.deletionSuccess}" value="#{true}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

**--- UPDATE**

Please keep correct file names in navigation-rule

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/detail.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>deletionSuccess</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/overview.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect include-view-params="true"/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

and please add to `detail.xhtml`:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" >
   <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
   <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

or remove 
`<p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?"/>`
from `<p:commandLink>` tag

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I added some new code but I'm still not able to show the success message. I would appreciate a new response. My Bean is ViewScoped.

Comment: do you use primefaces? which version? Your Bean is ViewScoped from  `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` package?;

Comment: Primefaces 4.0 and javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped

Comment: please try with `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` and if it will not work then I will try with PrimeFaces and `p:commandLink`

Comment: Okay I found the reason why it is not working :)
you forget to add `include-view-params="true"` to `<redirect>` tag in `faces-config.xml` :)

I added update to my answear with correct navigation rule

Comment: IT WORKS, thank you very very much!!! But can you explain, why you can't use request-param?

Comment: Do you mean `<redirect-param>` in `<navigation-rule>`? You can use it

Comment: But I must use a bean variable, it's not possible to solve it only with the navigation-rule and without the metadata?
<redirect include-view-params="true">
 <redirect-param>
    <name>deletionSuccess</name>
    <value>true</value>
        </redirect-param>
</redirect>